# Protractor "- Failed: Cannot read property 'ver' of null"

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am facing an annoying issue with protractor while trying to launch a test.

Protractor version: 5.1.2

protractor.conf.js

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/src/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
  },  
  rootElement: '*[ng-app]',
};
```

The end-to-end test file "app.comp.e2e-spec.js"

```
import { browser, element, by, $ } from 'protractor';

describe('testproject App', function() {

  it('should display message saying app works', (done) => {
    browser.get('/');
    expect($('.my-span').isPresent()).toBe(true);
    return done();
  });

});
```

Each time I launch the test (protractor protractor.conf.js) I run into this error message :

```
1) testproject App should display message saying app works
- Failed: Cannot read property 'ver' of null

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 0.984 sec.
[11:27:52] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:27:52] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[11:27:52] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[11:27:52] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

I have of course an Angular app running at localhost:8080/index and it's work perfectly when accessing manually with a browser. Would someone have any idea to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thnx for all the info, but is this really all the log you have, is there no reference to a file in the log?

Comment: @wswebcreation Please find the full command output here : https://pastebin.com/3tLdGGvw

Comment: As I remember there is an option in the `jasmine-spec-reporter` to enable stacktrace in the log, can you turn that on or disable the `jasmine-spec-reporter` and place the log here again?

Comment: The error "Cannot read property x of null" is indicative of a typescript error. You are referencing ts-node so presumably you are using typescript - can you post your tsconfig.json ?

Comment: @wswebcreation Output with stack trace enabled: https://pastebin.com/1G9tYXtU

Comment: @M.Hudson Here is the tsconfig.json https://pastebin.com/4jK1e5h2

Comment: Based on your logging there is an error in your `(C:\Users\bilel\Desktop\ng\e2e\app.component.e2e-spec.ts:4:5) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bilel\Desktop\ng\e2e\app.component.e2e-spec.ts:3:1)` Did you paste the correct `app.component.e2e-spec.ts` file here?

Comment: @wswebcreation Yes it's the good file, I've pasted it here https://pastebin.com/ptjLbgkz
I don't see any problem with this file, I may be wrong

Comment: @Bil5 hey! I'm having the same problem. Did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was raised when an unexpected alert message was triggered during the app configuration/load. This happened due to failure to communicate with an external system, which only happened in Travis CI. As this was the only error message, it took a long time to determine the real cause. (The eureka moment was when I followed the browser.get() call with a .then() with separate deliberately-failing expect() tests in the normal and error handlers; this replaced the 'ver' failure with a more informative and useful failure message about an unexpected alert.)

The solution was to remove the dependency on the external system (which shouldn't have been in the test configuration in the first place).

Answer (score -1):

```
expect($('.my-span').isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

isPresent() returns a Promise not true or false.

To check element is present, use the value that promise returns:

```
element(anyFinder).isPresent().then(function(isPresent) {
  if ( isPresent) {
   // The element is present
  } else {
  // The element is not present
}
});
```

Comment: That's partially true. With Jasmine you can still use  `expect($('.my-span').isPresent()).toBe(true);`, it will resolve it from within Jasmine

Comment: Thanks Dharam but as wswebcreation said, it's still possible to use the other way, anyway with your code I've the same error message

Comment: Add some wait to you code and and also check by using    
    .isDisplayed()).toEqual(false);

Comment: I already tried to add things like browser.wait but result was the same. Furthermore, as I see, for some people it works fine without any additional boostraping so I would like to understand what is going wrong, Testing Angular2 with protractor seems (at this time) to be something quite inconsistant yet.

Comment: @Bil5, testing with Angular 2 is not inconsistant. Can you please provide more info as asked above?

Comment: @wswebcreation Of course, what kind of information should I provide?